# Chicago Boss: Routes does not work in production mode?

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I created the `rahm_test_controller.erl` file in `src` directory, and added an action named `hello`.

In `/priv/rahm.routes`, I added this line for home page:

```
{"/",[{controller,"test"}, {action, "hello"}]}.
```

If I launch the server with `./init-dev.sh`, it works, but if I launch the server in production mode with `./init.sh start`, it does not work. When I open the home page, it says "No data received".

What's the problem here?

Comment: I've reproduced this on my machine as well, any answers?

Comment: Have you compiled the new code? `./init-dev.sh` does compilation on the fly, but `./init.sh start` requires the files to be compiled before running (`./rebar compile`). If this is not the problem, paste `log/console.log` and `log/error.log` messages here.